# Add compersion to all ActionResult without adding attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have too many **ActionResult** in my application and I want add gzip compersion to them.

is there any solution to avoid adding attribute to all **ActionResult**?
like inheriting or something?

this is my compersion code :

```
public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in MVC 3+ - add the Action Filter to the Global Action Filters.  In either Global.asax.cs or FilterConfig.cs (depending on how your projects is layed out), just add the filter in the method RegisterGlobalFilters.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new CompressFilter());
}
```

Comment: Concur with usr's answer as well - but, to answer your question, yes you can register a global action filter.  Handle gzip compression through IIS.

Comment: i ask you too : is there any better solution for compression ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should configure gzip compression in the web.config file for all content types where this makes sense. There is a built-in HTTP module for that.

The `response.Filter` method is not best practice doing HTTP compression in ASP.NET. Compression is an infrastructure concern that is handled for you.

Comment: if my IIS doesn't  enable this option the web.config setting wont work. but with this attribute its work all the time

Comment: This attribute compresses badly (because the BCL compression algorithm is known to be awful) and is slow. You're not using a good solution there.

Comment: is there any better solution for compression ?

Comment: Yes - use the built-in stuff. It's actually not hard to configure.